# Multiplication of a value by the probability of its occurrence.

Tags: probability

If a value occurs with certain probability, can the value be multiplied by that probability?  For instance, if $y$ occurs with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, does it make sense to say the value is actually $y \times \frac{1}{3}$? How does one interpret this phenomenon?

Comment: To elaborate, if $y$ occurs with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ and $z$ occurs with probability $\frac{2}{3}$, can I say the combined value is $\frac{y}{3} + \frac{2z}{3}$?

Comment: The formula that you wrote would be the “expected value” of the random variable, also called the “mean”, which for discrete random variables is a weighted average: i.e. weighted by the probabilities, just as you have done in your comment.

Comment: But to answer your first question, it does not make sense to say the value IS $y \times p(y)$. Once the random process has resulted in a realization, then the value is what it is. The “expected value” (which is somewhat of a misnomer), is the long term average of many independent trials from processes with identical distributions.

Comment: Thanks, Joe!  Makes sense.  In my case, $y$ is the realization of a random variable and I know the true value of this realization.  However, $y$ occurs with a certain probability (say, $\frac{1}{3}$).  So, I am trying to mathematically interpret this situation.

Comment: You’re welcome!  Interpreting probability can be quite challenging, and sometimes contentious, such as between frequentists and Bayesians.

Comment: Of course if $z=0$, the expectation or expected value is $y/3$.